# Defining user defined messages based on INET

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to define a custom HTTP message from Chunk base class in INET framework of OMNET++.

But msg compiler of OMNET is saying that chunk is unknown class.

My source code (HttpMessage.msg):

```
cplusplus {{
#include "inet/common/packet/chunk/Chunk.h"
}}
class HttpRequest extends Chunk
{
    string cookie;
}
```

I went for another code...

```
cplusplus {{
#include "inet/common/packet/chunk/FieldsChunk.h"
}}
class inet::FieldsChunk;
class HttpRequest extends FieldsChunk
{
    string cookie;
}
```

Now it says that "no matching constructor for initialization of '::inet::FieldsChunk"

Thanks....

Answer (score 3):

1. Try the following code:

   ```
   import inet.common.INETDefs;
   import inet.common.packet.chunk.Chunk;
   namespace inet;

   class HttpRequest extends Chunk {
       int cookie;
   }
   ```
2. Then go to `Properties` of your project, select `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | src folder | `Options...` | `Custom` and add the following line:

   ```
   MSGC:=$(MSGC) --msg6
   ```

   *Alternatively you can just create in `src` a new text file `makefrag`, without extension*, with the above line.

   ---

   Option `--msg6` tells the message compiler that should use a new method of import messages:

   > **--msg6**: Activate support for imports and other experimental features.
   >     Message files using the new features are not backward compatible
   >     and they need to be updated. For further info see src/nedxml/ChangeLog.
   >     Hint: To activate, add a makefrag file to your project with the
   >     following content:"MSGC:=$(MSGC) --msg6"

Comment: My project folder was different as that of inet, and I tried to refer it in project references! When I tried this, it says "mport statement unexpected NAME, expecting $end"... So I tried in inet's folder itself.. Then it worked! Thanks for helping...